# Can we set a redirection with dynamic content in url?

Tags: customization

I need to redirect users to profile page using a single url.

Ex:
Static link: [www.domain.com/profile/](http://www.domain.com/profile/)

when clicked,

[www.domain.com/profile/[USERNAME]/](http://www.domain.com/profile/%5BUSERNAME%5D/) <-- adds username

i need to change the [USERNAME] according to logged in user's username. can we do this in wordpress?

Ex2:  if user "Paul" logged in and click on [www.domain.com/profile/](http://www.domain.com/profile/) then he will redirect to [www.domain.com/profile/Paul/](http://www.domain.com/profile/Paul/)

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Are you looking for a plugin or help to implement it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a link with the user nickname as a part of it I would do something like this

```
<?php
// check if user is logged in
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    // get current user object
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // get user nickname
    $user_nickname = $current_user->data->user_nicename;

    // set the link href
    $link_href = 'www.domain.com/profile/' . $user_nickname;

    // output the link html
    echo '<a href="' . $link_href . '" title="title text here">Link text here</a>';
}
?>
```

Now, because I don't know where or how you want to add the link I made some generic code that will output the link with the current users nickname only if user is logged in

> EDIT

In order to output the link in a when using a wordpress text editor (wysiwyg) you will need a shortcode.

Same code as above but now in a shortcode

Add the following code inside your functions.php

```
add_shortcode('bt_redirect_user_link', 'bt_redirect_user_link');
function bt_redirect_user_link ($atts) {
    // check if user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // get current user object
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
        // get user nickname
        $user_nickname = $current_user->data->user_nicename;

        // set the link href
        $link_href = 'www.domain.com/profile/' . $user_nickname;

        // output the link html
        return '<a href="' . $link_href . '" title="title text here">Link text here</a>';
    }
}
```

To use the shortcode inside a text editor simply add `[bt_redirect_user_link]`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Much appreciated. Im trying to add a global redirection where i redirect users to specific url (www.domain.com/profile/) and code will add {username} then redirects to that page.

Comment: That's to broad, when do you want to redirect the user? does the user has to enter a specific url or does he have to click a button, or something like that?

Comment: Yes user will click a button where he will be redirected to www.domain.com/profile/. then the code will do the rest. code will automatically add username and redirect to url

www.domain.com/profile/ -> www.domain.com/profile/username

Comment: Well, my code outputs a link that a logged in user will be able to see and click, after clicking he will go to the url with his nickname. If thats all you need now i only need to know the location to place the link at

Comment: link will be on wordpress page content (placed via text editor). when user clicked on this link then your code executes. Hope this explanation is clear if not please let me know i will try to explain further. not much of a code savvy guy. apologize for that

Comment: Updated my code to include the new option, a shortcode you can use inside a wordpress text editor (wyiswyg)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. You are a life saver. just out of curiosity, can we set up a trigger to execute the code? like any one clicks on specific url, the code grabs the request and change the url. same scenario as 301 redirection. so we can put the link as a menu or as link in anywhere? url -> url/username

Comment: Its possible, yes. but from what you need (so we can put the link as a menu or as link in anywhere) this seems like the shortcode would handle it. if you want to redirect a user that entered a X url to a Y url based on if his logged in that's a different question, yes you can, it wil  require more logic but its possible.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast "if you want to redirect a user that entered a X url to a Y url based on if his logged in that's a different question" - that is literally the question OP asked. Not how to output a dynamic link.